# Copy word from 1 file to another using Bash

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to copy over only specific words from 1 text file to another.

this is what is inside my username2.txt:

```
jason,visitor
mark,staff
orlando,visitor
```

I'm trying to copy over only jason and orlando to another txt file so it'll just be like:

```
jason
orlando
```

this is currently my bash script (as of right now, it only creates a blank txt file):

```
#!/bin/bash

username="username2.txt"

while IFS=, read username1 group1; do
 if [ $group1 = "visitor" ]; then
   awk $username1 $username > reportvisitors.txt
 fi
 done < $username
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
awk $username1 $username > reportvisitors.txt
```

with

```
echo "$username1" >> reportvisitors.txt
```

---

**Update**

```
#!/bin/bash

username="username2.txt"

while IFS=, read username1 group1; do
 if [ "$group1" = "visitor" ]; then
   echo "$username1"
 fi
 done < $username > reportvisitors.txt
```

Comment: Tried it, Thanks! stupid question, am i only allowed to use "echo" for this scenario?

Comment: If you want to output the content of a variable, you can also use `printf`. See `help printf`.

Comment: Alright, anyway how can i make it overwrite instead? because if i bash it twice, it will display the names twice

Comment: Remove `>> reportvisitors.txt` and append `> reportvisitors.txt` to your `done` line.

Comment: i actually did tried it but it only displays orlando in the reportvisitors.txt, jason is nowhere to be found haha

Comment: sry cyrus im abit confused, isit like that? https://ibb.co/TvpXPVc

Answer (score 4):

This could be easily done with `awk` and we do not need to use a while loop for this since `awk` itself could read Input_file itself.

```
username="username2.txt"
awk -F, '$2=="visitor"{print $1}' "$username" > "reportvisitors.txt"
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation is, making field separator as `,` for all lines of Input_file(which is a shell variable named `username`). Then inside main program checking condition `$2=="visitor"` to check if 2nd field is visitor then printing 1st column. At last of this `awk` program sending output to `reportvisitors.txt`.

Comment: Tried it thanks! and thanks for the explanation as well !

Comment: @Kinja what about to accept that answer then, your problem is solved isn't it ? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the line 7 to

```
echo $username1 >> reportvisitors.txt
```

The Code should look like

```
#!/bin/bash
```

This part makes sure that an already existing file with the name is deleted

```
FILE=reportvisitors.txt
if test -f "$FILE"; then
    rm $FILE 
fi
```

from here on I have only edited line 5

```
username="username2.txt"

while IFS=, read username1 group1; do
    if [ $group1 = "visitor" ]; then
        echo $username1 >> reportvisitors.txt
    fi
done < $username
```

Comment: Alright, anyway how can i make it overwrite instead? because if i bash it twice, it will display the names twice

Comment: you can delete the files at the beginning of the code, but you will get an error message the first time you run it. It works anyway. Or add an if statement so it's just delet if there is a file

Comment: I just added my answer. That should be it. Isn't it?